# Monitor Battery Level

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, battery, batterylevel

I have a broadcast receiver in my program to monitorize the battery level like so:

```
private BroadcastReceiver batteryInformation= new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
         int iLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
         int iScale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
         int iTemperature = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
         int iVoltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);

         Float realLevel = ( (float) iLevel / (float) iScale * 100.f );
     }
}
```

and then i start the receiver:

```
registerReceiver( batteryInformation, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

and it works fine. This is the correct way to monitor level, scale, temperature and other battery parameter.

Is there a way to monitor only level variation?

Comment: What do you mean by to monitor only level variation?

Comment: In Android OS when battery level changes every 1% the broadcast is done  with an Intent. And this is done over framework level. To monitor the level variation you need to use NDK and do system level code. Can, you describe your requirement why you need the level variation monitor.????

Comment: With this receiver I get also the temperature level even if the level (57% for example) is the same. I want to get only level variation